# Unable to access view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, debugging, asp.net-mvc-views

On debugging in my controller I get a valid model as

[image]

However as execution reaches the `return view(model);`

I get

[image]

What is this error about ?

Answer (score 1):

Controller is unable to find the specified view which contains your IndexViewModel

Answer (score 0):

It would appear you haven't created a view in one of the required locations....looking at your error you should probably have a view here /Views/LoadProduct/Index.cshtml

Comment: I do have the view in that very location.This is what I am not getting.actually I am trying to load a selected product(to allow its editing) on the page that was used to create it.  Do you think its the fact that I am supplyng the productId as a parameter to the Index action that is causing this error ?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your full controller.  I Would have thought you would want your controller to be named "ProductController" and have a method on the controller called "Edit" that returns an ActionResult that takes an 'id' which is passed in from your index view i.e. your call to load a single product would not hit your index action.  Under Views you would then have Views/Product/Index.cshtml and Views/Product/Edit.cshtml

Comment: Yes thank you. I created another action named "edit" and working with it. Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the view for this action. Can you check if `Index.cshtml` exists in `Loadproduct` folder?